# Weblogic message Driven bean call error

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic, cdi, message-queue

I have strange error when I am trying to use a message-driven bean on oracle weblogic server.

When I add a new message t the queu and the server tries to call the message-driven bean I get the following error:

```
com.oracle.injection.provider.weld.WeldBeanManager createEjb
INFO: Could not find the weld descriptor for ejb: HelloWorldMessageDrivenBean
```

My bean looks like this:

```
@MessageDriven(mappedName = "jms/HelloWorldQueue", activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue")
})
public class HelloWorldMessageDrivenBean implements MessageListener {

    public HelloWorldMessageDrivenBean() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
    }
```

I can see the bean as deployed on the weblogic admin GUI.

Any idea what i might have missed?

Thanks!

Comment: According to this [example](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e15493/annotations.htm#BABDFEBB), retrieved from Oracle's documentation, you're missing the `name` attribute on your `@MessageDriven`.

Answer (score 3):

So the error seems to be a false alarm from my side, The message is only coming at the first run of the message driven bean and the bean is working correctly anyway. Since it is written with red on the console I thought that it is a bigger issue but it works correctly. So dont be afraid if you see the same red message.